# How to use react-i18next inside BASIC function (not component)?

Tags: react-i18next

I know that react-i18next work in every component: functional (with useTranslation) and class component (with withTranslation()) BUT I can't use translation inside a basic function like this:

```
const not_a_component = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  return t('translation')
};

const translate = not_a_component();
```

ERROR HOOKS !

Thanks !

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could just use `i18next` library for translation using javascript.
`react-i18next` is just a wrapper library on top of `i18next`.

Below is an example if you are already using `react-i18next` and it is configured.

```
import i18next from "i18next";

const not_a_component = () => {
  const result = i18next.t("key");
  console.log(result);
  return result;
};

export default not_a_component;
```

If you opt to use only `i18next`then you could simply get `t` function.
It all depends upon your requirement.

```
import i18next from 'i18next';

i18next.init({
  lng: 'en',
  debug: true,
  resources: {
    en: {
      translation: {
        "key": "hello world"
      }
    }
  }
}, function(err, t) {
  // You get the `t` function here.
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = i18next.t('key');
});
```

Hope that helps!!!

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can pass `t` as an additional parameter:

```js
const not_a_component = (t) => {
  return t('translation')
};

// Within a component
const { t } = useTranslation()
not_a_component(t)
```

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I was looking for. Simple and easy.

Answer (score 2):

if you have already initialized i18next somewhere, you may use i18next like this:

```
import { t } from "i18next";

const InYourComponent = () => {
    t('key')
}

const outside_of_components = () => {
    t('key')
}
```