# How to use translation i18n in React without hook?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-i18next

I need to do translation in my middleware (`import { Middleware } from 'redux'`) logic, but I can't use `useTranslation` hook (`import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'`). How do you standardly solve such situation?

Error message:

```
React Hook "useTranslation" is called in function "myFunction: Middleware<{}, RootStateType>" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function.
```

my code(shortened):

```
import PushNotificationIOS from '@react-native-community/push-notification-ios';
import { Middleware } from 'redux';
import { getType } from 'typesafe-actions';

const scheduleNotificationSettings = (notification: NotificationT): void => {
 PushNotificationIOS.scheduleLocalNotification({
        fireDate: notification.startDate,
        alertTitle: TRANSLATE_SOMEHOW(notification.titleKey),<--- ! HERE ! ¯\_( ❛ ͜ʖ ︡❛)_/¯
        alertBody: TRANSLATE_SOMEHOW(notification.bodyKey),  <--- ! HERE !
        alertAction: 'view',
        isSilent: false,
        repeatInterval: 'week',
      });
};

export const handleAction: Middleware<{}, RootStateType> = () => {
  return next => {
    return action => {
      const result = next(action);
      switch (action.type) {
        case getType(create): {
          createNotification(action.payload);
          break;
        }
        case getType(delete): {
          removeNotification(action.payload);
          break;
        }
        default:
          return result;
      }
      return result; //pass events to other middleware
    };
  };
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I hope I understand your problem correctly, but I assume you have initialized i18n already, so outside of react components don't use the hook just import it like this:

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
```

then use it:

```
i18n.t(youri18nKey);
```

Comment: that's what I thought too, but I'm getting only the keys not the translated values. In components I use it with the hook useTranslation (https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook). And initialisation is done in separate file. I'm new to this code, so maybe not the best indicies what can cause this. Thanks

Comment: You then may need to wait for i18next to have finished to initialize.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57864069/how-to-use-react-i18next-inside-basic-function-not-component

Answer (score 1):

if you have already initialized i18next somewhere, you may use i18next like this:

```
import { t } from "i18next";

const InYourComponent = () => {
    t('key')
}

const outside_of_components = () => {
    t('key')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 'next-i18next' package, then use `i18n` as follows:

```
import { useTranslation, i18n } from 'next-i18next';
```

and use it in functions like:

```
i18n?.t('common.your_key_here')
```