# React internalisation SPA using i18next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, internationalization, i18next

I need to translate my app, but i don't knomw how to use useTranslation() in the top-level files (i store there some consts which contain some text). One of this file is

```
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

const {t} = useTranslation()

    export const selectThemeOptions = [
      { value: "choose", text: "Choose theme" },
      { value: "Algebra", text: "Algebra" },
      { value: "Geometry", text: "Geomerty" },
      { value: "Programming", text: "Programming" },
      { value: "Logic", text: "Logic" },
    ];
```

so in this case i have an error:
src\Configs\ThemesOfProblems.js
Line 3:13:  React Hook "useTranslation" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

I need this array in my component, and it use in the next fragment :

```
<Form.Group as={Col} controlId="problemTheme">
                                <Form.Label>{t("userprofile.theme")}</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Select
                                    name="theme"
                                    value={values.theme}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    isValid={touched.theme && !errors.theme}
                                    isInvalid={!!errors.theme}
                                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                                >
                                    {selectThemeOptions.map((el, index) => {
                                        return <option key={index} value={el.value}> {el.text} </option>
                                    })}
                                </Form.Select>
                            </Form.Group>
```

And i've got a lot of such situations, i don't have any ideas how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Basically it says it has to be called in a react component. It could be called in a functional component where you return your jsx or a class component that has a render method in it. If you call the function outside of one of these, then you will get this error.

Comment: i know it, but how can i call it out of components

Comment: The only solution I can offer to this is by calling it in a component then sending it as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You called `const {t} = useTranslation();` outside of a React component, your `selectThemeOptions` file seems to be regular `JavaScript` due to the absence of `JSX` or a returning statement with your HTML.

**Here is the correct way to do it:**

```
/* Everything above this point is considered top-level, hence using your `useTranslation()` hook here would cause an error */

const Component = (props) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
}

export default Component;
```

**Here is a way to organise your translations:**

• Your `src` folder should contain an `i18n.js` file with the following code:

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import en from "../locales/en.json";
import ru from "../locales/ru.json";

const isReturningUser = "lang" in localStorage; // Returns true if user already used the website.
const savedLanguage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lang")); // Gets persisted language from previous visit.

// Get previously used language in case of returning user or set language to Russian by default.
const language = isReturningUser ? savedLanguage : "ru";

const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: en,
  },
  ru: {
    translation: ru,
  },
};

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
  resources,
  lng: language,
  keyseparator: false,
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false,
  },
});

export default i18n;
```

- Your `src` folder should contain a `locales` folder with json files of the languages your application uses. Example: `ru.json` and `en.json`:

```
{
  "choose": "Выбрать",
  "chooseATheme": "Выбрать тему",
  "algebra": "Алгебра",
  "geometry": "Геометрия",
  "programming": "Программирование",
  "logic": "Логика",
}
```

- Your component should look like this – note that the translations are in `json` files instead of your React component – :

```
import React from "react";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

const Component = (props) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

const selectThemeOptions = [
      { value: t("choose"), text: t("chooseATheme") },
      { value: t("algebra"), text: t("algebra") },
      { value: t("geometry"), text: t("geometry") },
      { value: t("programming"), text: t("programming") },
      { value: t("logic"), text: t("logic") },
    ];

return( //Your UI )
   
}

export default Component;
```

This way, your translations wouldn't be hard-coded on your `selectThemeOptions` and will adapt to whichever translation your `json` locales contain.

Please tell me if this works.

Edit: If you want a concrete example of implementation of my solution here it is: https://github.com/YHADJRABIA/ecommerce/tree/main/src

Edit2: There might be a better solution of doing this, this is merely what worked for me.

Edit3: Following Nikita's comment, here's a solution to use the translation function outside of a react component —[How to use react-i18next inside BASIC function (not component)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57864069/how-to-use-react-i18next-inside-basic-function-not-component)

P.S. Since you are from Belarus I assume that you want your translation to be made in Russian since Belarusian isn't as widely spoken.

Comment: I've got a lot of files whic store text, table's column's configs, yup's text fields and so on, so i understand that i can't now have these files(

Comment: Alright, so if I understand correctly your only concern is to get the `useTranslation()` hook to work in a non-React component. I'll try to figure this out and write back. EDIT: Here is what I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57864069/how-to-use-react-i18next-inside-basic-function-not-component

Comment: I edited my original post with a link that might help fix your problem.